# C++ templates and C preprocessor

Tags: c++, templates, c-preprocessor, dry

Consider for a moment this code. Is not important what the code do, but how template boilerplate code is written.

From boilerplate point of view, the code has some important advantages.

- much less boilerplate code.
- if you decide to take more template parameters, you change only class definition and the `#define`.

Disadvantages are obvious:

- using preprocessor
- not so readable
- just weird

Is there anything standardized like this?

---

```
#include <cstdio>

template<typename T>
struct Summator{
    Summator(T v1, T v2);

    T value1();
    T value2();

    T sum();

    bool great();

private:
    T v1;
    T v2;
};


#define Summator_(type) template<typename T> type Summator<T>


Summator_()::Summator(T v1, T v2) : v1(v1), v2(v2){};

Summator_(T)::value1(){
    return v1;
}

Summator_(T)::value2(){
    return v1;
}

Summator_(T)::sum(){
    return v1 + v2;
}

Summator_(bool)::great(){
    return v1 > v2;
}

int main(){
    Summator<int> s{ 5, 6 };

    printf("%d\n", s.sum() );
}
```

Comment: The closest is probably [`std::accumulate()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think he's referring to using `Summator_` to abbreviate the template definition *shiver*.

Comment: Not sure I understood the question, but why not using C++11 `using` directive?

Comment: This is about not having to write out `template<class T> /*return_type*/ Summator<T>::` in front of every out-of-class member function definition? There's some recent discussions about this on std-proposals, but definitely won't make C++17.

Comment: The point is not what the class do, but how boilerplate is written

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I thin the addition was just a toy example.  The point of the question is the #define.

Comment: For short functions, you may inline them in the class so no boiler plate.

Comment: Using the preprocessor like this is usually a leading cause of maintenance problems down the road. It's also easy to forget a little something that can cause weird errors, like how you yourself forgot the `T` in `Summator_()::Summator(...)`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Actually, no, that `T` is the return type, so the constructor shouldn't have anything.

Comment: See [P0223](http://wg21.link/P0223).

Comment: @T.C. Ah okay. And that kind of proves my first point.

Comment: @T.C. P0223 is very nice. I was looking for such feature, hope they include it some day...

Comment: @T.C.: and with P0223, that would open the possibility to implement friend function in the correct scope and possibly with specialization :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to avoid to have to write the whole template in front of every function definition?

I think most people who care about this rely on an IDE to generate empty function definitions / refactor existing functions?

I don't think using macro's is a good idea for this, just to save a little typing, feels like a maintenance nightmare in the making.

Answer (score 1):

Given that for most practical purposes, member functions of class templates have to be inline, you might as well define them in the body of the calls.  Particularly for tiny functions like this.

Obviously real class templates are likely to have one or two non-trivial functions - but then you only need the boiler plate for those one or two functions.

There is nothing defined in the standard to help with this, and I'm not sure I'd want there to be.  If you must do it, remember to #undef the define afterwards (because otherwise you will pollute the #define namespace of the user of your class).

Answer (score 0):

> much less boilerplate code.

No, it's the same

> if you decide to take more template parameters, you change only class definition and the #define.

read: if you decide to completely change the design... maybe you might save some typing (but then again, maybe not)

> using preprocessor

Yup - so that's a no right there.

> not so readable

so "no" again

> just weird

irrelevant

> Is there anything standardized like this?

clearly not